# umlaut is not shown java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Servlet not showing umlauts? what should I do?

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String myname = request.getParameter("benutzer");
        String mypass = request.getParameter("pass");
        
        PrintWriter myaus = response.getWriter();
        myaus.println("Deine Benutzername und pass ist  :  "+myname+ " :: "+mypass);
}
```

I would also like a sentence with an umlaut to be Displayer.

Comment: Fix your code formatting.

Comment: Include the umlaut in your hard-coded text so we have an example.

Answer (score 0):

Return a proper minimal [HTML 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) page. Like [this example](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-minimal-html-document-html5-edition/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title goës here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Côntënt goës hérè</p> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Change `en` to your human language of choice.